# What are the different forms of "косарь"?

Tags: падежи, сленг

In Russian "косарь" means a thousand. But what are the different forms and cases of "косарь"? For example, can you say "Это двухкосарёвый вопрос на Stack Exchange русского языка"? What are the dative or genitive cases of "косарь"?

P.S. "Косарь" is, as far as I understand, informal. Russians would usually use it in dialogues like "Сколько у тебя с собой рублей?" -- "Пять косарей."

Comment: related
http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/47466/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F

Comment: - Сколько у тебя с собой рублей
*This immediately indicates a foreigner*
- Пять косарей
*Now that's just rude, using slang when talking to a foreigner*

Comment: @НадеждаТарашкевич I don't think using slang is rude though - in this particular case, it's just that it sounds unnatural.

Comment: We don't use it much nowadays, I think.

Comment: This word is so outdated!

Comment: @НадеждаТарашкевич, and how exactly does it indicate?

Comment: @bipll, "сколько рублей?" is only for measuring 1-ruble coins (~2 cent).   "сколько денег?" or just "сколько?" is for total money amont.

Comment: @НадеждаТарашкевич what if am supposed to have rubles, dollars and francs in my pocket? Then "сколько у тебя с собой рублей" would be a natural question.

Comment: As Russian native speaker I would be really surprised if I heard someone using this word nowadays

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Это двухкосарёвый вопрос на Stack Exchange русского языка" will immediately give you away as a non-native speaker who imporperly tries to use some Russian slang.

"Косарь" is used only for amount of money - it's indeed 1000, but there's also another term - "штука" which seem to be used wider.

That said, while it's easy to provide all cases, you need to understand that it's just not use with the majority of them:

- *Им.* Косарь, косари:

  > Ух ты, целый косарь?
- *Р.* Косаря, косарей:

  > Чёрт, косаря не хватает, чтоб купить.
- *Д.* Косарю, косарям (Hardly used in this form)
- *В.* Косарь, косари:

  > Я ругаю себя за этот косарь, который я ему должен.
- *Тв.* косарём, косарями:

  > Да подавись ты своим косарём, жадина.
- *Пр.* косаре, косарями:

  > О косаре забудь.

Last, it worth to mention that unlike "штука" which easily is used for denominating multiple thousands, "косарь" is used more often when talking about one thousand.

Comment: That is why I added an example at the end, I heard that it was usually mentioned when speaking about money.

Comment: This slang word is very limited to certain parts of Russia. People from some areas will not understand this word.

Comment: @L_Pav nevertheless it was part of the question, this is why I've mentioned it, also has added usages in different cases.

Comment: Example of usage in Dative I can think of: "У шефа день рождения скоро — собери с народа по косарю на подарок".